# c# function not in namespace

Tags: c#

I have declared a file (UnstuckPackage.cs) in a folder with other cs files.

In another cs file I reference this file (Using folder/UnstuckPackage.cs).

When I call the class in this file Visual Studio does not give an error but when I compile the solutions it yields an error and says me that the class that I have declared is not in a namespace or is not a referenced assembly.

In this folder there are too many cs files that are in the same program, but I recall only this (the one I added after) is not recognized.

Extract of code:
The UnstuckPackage.cs:

```
using game.Core;
using game.Domain;

namespace game.GameObject.CommandPackets
{
    [PacketHeader("$Unstuck", PassNonParseablePacket = true, Authority = 
    AuthorityType.User)]
    public class UnstuckPacket : PacketDefinition
    {
        public static string ReturnHelp()
        {
            return "$Unstuck";
        }
    }
}
```

And an extract of cs that recall UnstuckPackage.cs:

```
using game.Domain;
using game.GameObject;
using game.GameObject.CommandPackets;

namespace game.Handler
{

    public class CommandPacketHandler : IPacketHandler
    {

        // <summary>
        //     $Unstuck Command
        // </summary>
        // <param name = "unstuckPacket" ></ param >
        public void Unstuck(UnstuckPacket unstuck_element)
        {
            // CODE HERE
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Unfortunately it's hard to help with only descriptions like this - if you could provide a complete example, it would be easier to help you. At the moment we don't know whether the two classes are in the same project, whether maybe you've made a typo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reference the class using it's namespace/folder name.

```
namespace project.namespace
{
    class test
    {
    }
}
```

in the other class you have to do the following

```
using project.namespace;
namespace project.namespace2
{
        class test2
        {
             //access test class here
        }
}
```

If the class exist in another project or dll you have to add a reference to them using project properties then add the using line to the class namespace.

Edit: class namespace should be the same as folder name, make sure you didn't do any changes on it and if so use it instead of your folder name.

Comment: "using it's namespace not folder name", unless you did something odd, the folder name **is** the namespace

Comment: Not necessarily, the namespace name can be different than the folder name check [this link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3196556a-0223-438c-b4fb-c76f72f7fccc/c-project-folders-and-namespaces?forum=Vsexpressvcs)

Comment: I said "unless you do something odd". Folder hierarchy is the most common way to work in .NET and it is very weird to use another hierarchy

Comment: I know it is an odd thing but doable which make it worth to be mentioned

Comment: In the "Main" cs i have a class, in this class i have a method that get in input an object of UnstuckPackage class, if i don't understand the reply say me please

Comment: Seems there's no problem in the code you posted, but are these two classes in the same project ?

Comment: Yes, they are in the same project